# FME merge features (many-to-one) with priority

Tags: merge, fme-form

I'm new to FME.

Suppose I want to join Table A to Table B based on the ID column (see below).
If table B has more features for a certain ID, than table A, I want the merger to join only the most important records of table B.
This means: first join features with `Priority == 1`, features with `Priority == 2` etc.

I can use the `FeatureMerger` with the `Requestor` being Table A, the `Supplier` Table B, and `Join On` will be `ID = ID`, but how can I implement the priority rule as described?

I'm using FME 2021.2

Table A (both tables come without geometry):

```
ID  Att_1   Att_2
1000    A   D
2000    A   D
2000    A   E
3000    A   F
4000    A   D
5000    A   D
6000    A   D
7000    A   D
7000    A   E
7000    A   F
```

and Table B:`

```
ID  Att_3   Priorty
1000    Q   3
2000    Q   2
2000    R   2
3000    T   2
4000    Q   3
4000    T   2
5000    M   3
5000    U   1
6000    W   1
7000    T   1
```

desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FeatureMerger joins the first supplier it finds (unless you have Process Duplicate Suppliers set), so the simplest thing is to use a Sorter transformer on the suppliers and sort by priority.

Then the first Supplier will be the highest priority, which is the one you want to join.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this, on the suppliers:

- StatisticsCalculator group by ID, analyze Priority to find MinPriority for each ID.
- Tester, pass features where Priority = MinPriority to keep only the features with the highest priority.

Then use the FeatureMerger, Process Duplicate Suppliers, Generate List. After this explode the listelements to features from the Merged ouputport using a ListExploder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Does this only join the minimum priority feature, or does it join all features ranging from 1 to 3 in that order?

Comment: Only the minimum priority features, but you will end up with 4 records with ID 2000. ADQ, AEQ, ADR, AER.